# best practices for picking ports for running local angular and node applications?

Tags: node.js, angular, networking

This is silly, but our internal ecosystem of apps is growing. Each app has an angular app and a NodeJS API. Of course, we started 5 years ago with all the defaults (so `4200` for Angular and `3000` for NodeJS).

I would like to clean-up and set some guidelines for our teams when it comes to picking ports for new applications. Basically, if we go to `5200` for our 1st app Angular, then `5201` would be the recommended port for the associated NodeJS API. Then the next Angular app would be `5202` and NodeJS `5203`.

I do see a somewhat complete [list of reserved/assigned ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). But **are there best practices out there about choosing ports for local development that won't interfere with other official services?**

Answer (score 1):

According to the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA), there are 3 ranges of ports:

- System Ports (0-1023)
- User Ports (1024-49151)
- And the Dynamic and/or Private Ports (49152-65535)

This is not completely true, you can use System Ports as long as they are not being used by another service.

NodeJS considers that 3000 is safety because it's between the user ports.

For further information you can take a look into the [RFC 6335](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335) which is the reference for the [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)